# How to determine if function argument is a sequence in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

On my way to write a simple traversal through `auto` generated data structures I was wondering why `type_traits` do not provide something like `std::is_sequence`.

I'm using this `make_array` :

```
template <typename... T>
  constexpr auto make_array(T&&... values) 
  -> std::array< typename std::decay< typename std::common_type<T...>::type>::type, sizeof...(T)> {
    return {std::forward<T>(values)...};
  }
```

to create structures like this:

```
auto z = make_array(
    make_array('h','e','l','l','o'),
    make_array('w','o','r','l','d')
 );
```

The elements could be of different types and dimensions as well.

Later I'd like to support more complex uses such as `func(1,2,MyClass(3),4.0,make_array(5,6,7),std::make_tuple(8.0,"9.1011",12))` ,

or
`func({13,14,15})`, but that I consider as a 2nd step.

(Whether or not such ideas will ever make it into my project I don't yet know, I'm just curious.)

My approach is to write two overloaded, templated functions `func`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_sequence<T>::value, void>::type
func(T& t) {
  std::cout << "\n\tfunc(t) => " << t << ' ';
}


template<typename SeqT> 
typename std::enable_if<is_sequence<SeqT>::value, void>::type
func(SeqT&  s) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(SeqT& s)...";
  for(auto iter=std::begin(s);iter!=std::end(s);++iter) func(*iter);
  std::cout << "\n...func(SeqT& s)...";
}
```

And with the help of

```
template <typename T>
class is_sequence {
private:
    typedef char YesType[1];
    typedef char NoType[2];

    template <typename C> static YesType& test(decltype(std::begin(C{})));
    template <typename C> static NoType& test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(YesType) };
};
```

(idea stolen from [here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/02/notes-on-c-sfinae.html))

It seems to work:

`func(z);`

Prints

```
func(SeqT& s)...
func(SeqT& s)...
        func(t) => h 
        func(t) => e 
        func(t) => l 
        func(t) => l 
        func(t) => o 
...func(SeqT& s)
func(SeqT& s)...
        func(t) => w 
        func(t) => o 
        func(t) => r 
        func(t) => l 
        func(t) => d 
...func(SeqT& s)
...func(SeqT& s)
```

Here come my questions:

(1) I don't think my need and general approach is too special. But the wise C++ guys obviously did not see the need to put something like `is_sequence` into the standard. What am I missing here?

(2) What other suggestions do you have for me?

Comment: I think it comes down to the fact that `is_sequence` is a loosely defined concept. What exactly is allowed as a sequence and what is not? Is a string a sequence or a value for example? If you mean "can I do a range-based for loop on this type", then that is one specific scenario that fits your use case, and as you have shown, writing a type_trait for it is only a couple of lines of code. You can adapt it and you know exactly what you get. Also just a note that there are much simpler ways to write that kind of type_trait with c++11, 14 17 and even more so with concepts in c++20.

Comment: i dont completely understand the aim. You need a `common_type` to create the `array`, but eg `make_array(5,6,7)` and `std::make_tuple(8.0,"9.1011",12)` have no `common_type` afaik

Comment: already `make_array( make_array('h','e','l','l','o'),  make_array('w','o','r','l','d','!') );` (note the extra char in the second parameter) would fail, unless I misread your code

Comment: Here is a [concept version](https://godbolt.org/z/Wq5qfzPq1) of is_sequence for reference.

Comment: And here is one that [works in C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/YojdWd4b5). Note that the one you found is a bit of an anachronism. This trick with `Yes` and `No` was common before C++11, but then on the other hand it is using `decltype` which is only available since C++11. (mine isnt necessarily the most idiomatic either)

Comment: ... and if you merely want to overload based on `T` being sequence or not, you actually don't need the trait, but you can overload like I overloaded `helper` directly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all Your comments.

I understand my C++-idiom looks outdated. Apart from that I learned "modern C++ programming" based on C++98 I still see most of my clients hesitating to allow more recent concepts introduced since C++11. I decided to stick to C++17 for now ...

I'd like to come up with my 2nd step work-in-progress result.

The set of overloaded functions `func(..)` supports `std::tuple`, where of course the term "sequence" appears even more questionable than in case of ranges.

And I added some support for `constexpr`, demonstrated by a set of `constexpr` template function overloads `count(..)`, each of them returning the number of *leaves* (I hope that term is clear enough in the context) in their subtree.

Another note: strings are *not* taken as sequences here.

Below You find the complete program, compiled with gcc and --std=c++17.
Of course any comments are welcome ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <typename... T>
  constexpr auto make_array(T&&... values) 
  -> std::array< typename std::decay< typename std::common_type<T...>::type>::type, sizeof...(T)> {
    return {std::forward<T>(values)...};
  }

template <typename T>
struct is_seq {
    template <typename U>
    static auto helper(U t) -> decltype(std::begin(t),std::true_type{}) {return{};}
    static auto helper(...) -> std::false_type { return{};}
    static const bool value = decltype(helper(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_tuple {
    template <typename U,int ix=0>
    static auto helper(U t) -> decltype(std::get<ix>(t),std::true_type{}) {return{};}
    static auto helper(...) -> std::false_type { return{};}
    static const bool value = decltype(helper(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};



template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<(!is_seq<T>::value) and (!is_tuple<T>::value) , void>::type
func(T& t) {
  std::cout << '<' << t << '>';
}

template<typename SeqT> 
typename std::enable_if<is_seq<SeqT>::value, void>::type
func(SeqT&  s) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(SeqT& s)...";
  for(auto iter=std::begin(s);iter!=std::end(s);++iter) func(*iter);
  std::cout << "\n...func(SeqT& s)";
}

template<typename SeqT> 
typename std::enable_if<is_seq<SeqT>::value, void>::type
func(const SeqT&  s) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(const SeqT& s)...";
  for(auto iter=std::begin(s);iter!=std::end(s);++iter) func(*iter);
  std::cout << "\n...func(const SeqT& s)";
}

template<class ...TL> 
void func(const std::tuple<TL...>& tp) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(const tuple<TL>& tp)...";
  std::apply([](auto&&... args) {(...,func(args));}, tp);
  std::cout << "\n...func(const tuple<TL>& tp)";
}

template<typename T>
void func(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(il)...";
  for(auto iter=il.begin();iter!=il.end();++iter) func(*iter);
  std::cout << "\n...func(il)";
}


template<typename ...TL>
void func(const TL&...  tl) {
  std::cout << "\nfunc(t,tl)... ";
  (...,func(tl));
  std::cout << "\n...func(t,tl)";
}

void func(...) {
  std::cout << "func(...)";
}

template<class ...TL> 
constexpr std::size_t count(const std::tuple<TL...>& tp) ;

template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<(!is_seq<T>::value) and (!is_tuple<T>::value) , std::size_t>::type
count(const T& /*t*/) {
  return 1;
}

constexpr std::size_t count(const std::string& ) {
  return 1;
}

template<typename SeqT> 
constexpr typename std::enable_if<is_seq<SeqT>::value, std::size_t>::type
count(const SeqT&  s) {
  std::size_t result(0);
  for(auto iter=std::begin(s);iter!=std::end(s);++iter) {
    result += count(*iter);
  }
  return result;
}

template <size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts), std::size_t>::type
countImpl(const std::tuple<Ts...>& /*tup*/) {
    return 0;
}
  
template <size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Ts)),std::size_t>::type
countImpl(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup) {
    return count(std::get<I>(tup)) + countImpl<I + 1>(tup);
}

template<class ...TL> 
constexpr std::size_t count(const std::tuple<TL...>& tp) {
  return countImpl(tp);
}


template<typename T>
std::size_t count(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
  std::size_t result(0);
  for(auto iter=il.begin();iter!=il.end();++iter) {
    result += count(*iter);
  }
  return result;
}


template<typename ...TL>
constexpr std::size_t count(const TL&...  tl) {
  std::size_t result(0);
  result = ( ... + count(tl) ) ;
  return result;
}

constexpr std::size_t count(...) {
  return 0;
}

struct X {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& ) {
  os << "X{}";
  return os;
}

#define TEST(x) { std::cout << "\n" << #x << ":\t" ; x ;}
#define TEST2(x) { std::cout << "\n" << #x << ":\t" << x ;}

int main(int , char** argv)  {
  std::cout << "\nthis is " << argv[0] << " running ...";

  std::array<double,13> da;
  auto t=std::make_tuple("hello",1,"world",3.1415);

  TEST(func(1))
    TEST(func())
    TEST(func(t))
    TEST(func(std::array<int,19>{11,12,13}))  
    TEST(func(da))
    TEST(func(X()))
    TEST(func(1,2,3))
    TEST(func(X{},X()))
    TEST(func({'a','b','c'})) 

    auto z = make_array(
      make_array('h','e','l','l','o'),
      make_array('w','o','r','l','d')
      );
  TEST(func(z))

    TEST(func(
        make_array('h','e','l','l','o'),
        std::vector<std::string>{"very","very"},
        std::make_tuple('c','o',make_array('o','l')),
        make_array('w','o','r','l','d','!')
        ));

  std::cout << "\n";
  TEST2(count(1,2,3,4));

  constexpr auto c1 = count(1,2,3,4);
  std::cout << "\nconstexpr auto c1 = count(1,2,3,4):" << c1;

  std::cout << "\n\n";

  constexpr auto c2 = count(
    make_array('h','e','l','l','o'),
    make_array("very","(very)"),
    std::make_tuple('c','o',make_array('o','l')),
    make_array("world","!!")
    );
  std::cout << "\ncount(...):" << c2;

  std::cout << "\n...bye\n";
  return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
this is ./sfinae-is-sequence.exe running ...
func(1):
func(t,tl)... <1>
...func(t,tl)
func(): func(...)
func(t):
func(const tuple<TL>& tp)...<hello><1><world><3.1415>
...func(const tuple<TL>& tp)
func(std::array<int,19>{11,12,13}):
func(const SeqT& s)...<11><12><13><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0>
...func(const SeqT& s)
func(da):
func(SeqT& s)...<0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0>
...func(SeqT& s)
func(X()):
func(t,tl)... <X{}>
...func(t,tl)
func(1,2,3):
func(t,tl)... <1><2><3>
...func(t,tl)
func(X{},X()):
func(t,tl)... <X{}><X{}>
...func(t,tl)
func({'a','b','c'}):
func(il)...<a><b><c>
...func(il)
func(z):
func(SeqT& s)...
func(SeqT& s)...<h><e><l><l><o>
...func(SeqT& s)
func(SeqT& s)...<w><o><r><l><d>
...func(SeqT& s)
...func(SeqT& s)
func( make_array('h','e','l','l','o'), std::vector<std::string>{"very","very"}, std::make_tuple('c','o',make_array('o','l')), make_array('w','o','r','l','d','!') ):
func(t,tl)... 
func(const SeqT& s)...<h><e><l><l><o>
...func(const SeqT& s)
func(const SeqT& s)...
func(const SeqT& s)...<v><e><r><y>
...func(const SeqT& s)
func(const SeqT& s)...<v><e><r><y>
...func(const SeqT& s)
...func(const SeqT& s)
func(const tuple<TL>& tp)...<c><o>
func(const SeqT& s)...<o><l>
...func(const SeqT& s)
...func(const tuple<TL>& tp)
func(const SeqT& s)...<w><o><r><l><d><!>
...func(const SeqT& s)
...func(t,tl)

count(1,2,3,4): 4
constexpr auto c1 = count(1,2,3,4):4


count(...):13
...bye
```